# How to return a nested JSON format with given table structure using Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

If I have some table structure as below, how should I return the following JSON format using Eloquent ORM?

Table structure:

```
authors
    id - integer
    name - string

posts
    id - integer
    author_id - integer
    title - string

images
    id - integer
    post_id - integer
    filename - string
```

JSON format I expect to return:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jeffrey",
    "posts": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Hello World",
        "images": [
          {
            "id": 12,
            "filename": "my-image.jpg"
          },
          {
            "id": 13,
            "filename": "your-image.jpg"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "images": [
          {
            "id": 20,
            "filename": "his-image.jpg"
          },
          {
            "id": 22,
            "filename": "her-image.jpg"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

- Table structure: an author may have many posts, a post may have many images
- JSON format: images are nested in post, posts are nested in author

**Edited**

Thanks for the reminder, I also added their Models:

```php
<?php  

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Author extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

```php
<?php  

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
    }
}
```

```php
<?php  

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you coded anything in PHP to get you to this result? If so show us, as we work better from a starting point, and ofter code adds lots of information to the question

Comment: If you are creating api read about eloquent resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the relation Posts to your Author model and relation Images to your Posts model you will be able to make the request like this and it will take all of the data for you.

```
Author::with('posts.images')->get();
```